# Set browser used for debugging sharepoint project

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, organization-browser

I have a visual studio 2010 sharepoint project which I want to debug. I would like to set the browser used for debugging.

I could probably set the browser if I had an aspx-Page in the project, but I don´t have one.

Comment: Which version of VS do you use?

Comment: updated question!

Answer (score 2):

For VisualStudio 2010 this extension might work for you:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Set the browser you want to use as the default browser in windows
2. Set it as startup program for debugging by:

   2.1. Right-click project select properties

   2.2 In the Debug tab fill out Start external program and Command line arguments like this:

[image]